# Removing all 'not sql' taggs from string

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to remove all elements from my text file that are not from sql.
I got a text file with sql and html all combined and I don't know how to filter the html stuff away from my text.

I hope it can be done with php.

What I tried:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ruben
 * Date: 16-5-2017
 * Time: 11:51
 */

$paths = [
'users' => [
    'dir' => __DIR__ . '/Voorbeelddata/293-Consumentenelektronica',
    'strategies' => ['insert']
],
'product' => [
    'dir' => __DIR__ . '/Voorbeelddata/14675-GSM en telecom/CREATE 
Users.sql',
    'strategies' => ['create']
],
];

$resultDir = __DIR__ . '/Results/';

//$content = file_get_contents($path);
$arr = array();

foreach ($paths as $prefix => $filter) {
if (is_dir($filter['dir'])) {
    $files = scandir($filter['dir']);

    foreach (array_diff($files, ['.', '..']) as $file) {
        readScriptFile($filter['dir'] . '/' . $file, $prefix . '-' . $file, 
$resultDir, $filter);
    }
} else {
    readScriptFile($filter['dir'], $prefix, $resultDir, $filter);
}
}

var_dump($arr);

function readScriptFile($file, $prefix, $resultDir, $filter) {
$arr = [];

if ($r = @fopen($file, 'r')) {
    while (!feof($r)) {
        $row = filter(fgets($r), $filter);

        if (!is_null($row)) {
            array_push($arr, [$row]);
        }
    }

    fclose($r);

    if (is_array($arr)) {
        $w = @fopen($resultDir . $prefix . '.sql', 'w');

        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            $row = fwrite($w, reset($item));

        }

        fclose($w);
    }
}
}

function filter($row, $filter) {
$filtered = null;

if (in_array('create', $filter['strategies'])) {
    if (isset($row) && strpos($row, 'CREATE') !== false) {

        $filtered = $row;
    }
}

if (in_array('insert', $filter['strategies'])) {
    if (isset($row) && strpos(!is_null($filtered) ? $filtered: $row, 'INSERT') !== false) {

        $filtered = $filtered ?? $row;
    }
}

return $filtered;
}
```

A little bit of the text-file:

```
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_5_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_1_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_3_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_7_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_6_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_4_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_8_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918244,'dt_2_180931918244.jpg')
INSERT Items(ID,Titel,Categorie,Postcode,Locatie,Land,Verkoper,Prijs,Valuta,Conditie,Thumbnail,Beschrijving) VALUES (180931918636,'SeXXy Fashion Treggings in Leder-Look Blauw Mt.L',31023,'7325GG','Nederland','NL','novofashion1','33.95','EUR','Nieuw met labels','img180931918636.jpg','<UL>
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">SeXXy Fashion Treggings in Leder-Look</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">** NEW FASHION STYLES **</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Kleur : Blauw</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Maat : L</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Materiaal : 97% Polyester, 3% Elasthan</SPAN></SPAN> </LI></UL>


            <CENTER>
            <IMG SRC=''http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/sell/templates/images/k2/tagline.gif'' BORDER=''0'' />
            <BR />
            <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" SIZE="2">Gemaakt door <A HREF="http://pages.ebay.nl/turbo_lister/">eBay Turbo Lister</A>.
            <BR />De gratis aanbiedingstool. Bied je objecten snel en gemakkelijk aan en beheer je actieve objecten.
            </FONT>
            </CENTER>
            ')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918636,'dt_2_180931918636.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918636,'dt_1_180931918636.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918636,'dt_5_180931918636.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918636,'dt_4_180931918636.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918636,'dt_3_180931918636.jpg')
INSERT Items(ID,Titel,Categorie,Postcode,Locatie,Land,Verkoper,Prijs,Valuta,Conditie,Thumbnail,Beschrijving) VALUES (180931918777,'SeXXy Fashion Treggings in Leder-Look Rood Mt.L',31023,'7325GG','Nederland','NL','novofashion1','33.95','EUR','Nieuw met labels','img180931918777.jpg','<UL>
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">SeXXy Fashion Treggings in Leder-Look</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">** NEW FASHION STYLES **</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Kleur : Rood</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Maat : L</SPAN></SPAN> 
<LI><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: larger"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Materiaal : 97% Polyester, 3% Elasthan</SPAN></SPAN> </LI></UL>
            <CENTER>
            <IMG SRC=''http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/sell/templates/images/k2/tagline.gif'' BORDER=''0'' />
            <BR />
            <FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" SIZE="2">Gemaakt door <A HREF="http://pages.ebay.nl/turbo_lister/">eBay Turbo Lister</A>.
            <BR />De gratis aanbiedingstool. Bied je objecten snel en gemakkelijk aan en beheer je actieve objecten.
            </FONT>
            </CENTER>
            ')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918777,'dt_2_180931918777.jpg')
INSERT Illustraties (ItemID,IllustratieFile) VALUES (180931918777,'dt_1_180931918777.jpg')
```

And this is just 1% of the code so doing it manually is not an option.

Comment: This html seems to be the data of some rows (column : `Beschrijving`) so why to remove it?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos In the column `Beschrijving` I need to get the html away, so it  only leaves the `Kleur: blauw`, `Maat: L` and  `Material: 97% Polyester` in it

Comment: Wouldn't it then be easier to import it into a (temporary) database (if it's not in one already, in its current condition) and then update the rows by using an HTML parser, in PHP, for instance? It appears the SQL is malformed though (`INSERT Illustraties` in stead of `INSERT INTO Illustraties`), so not sure it's a viable option, in its current state.